# Python Parse through String to create variable

Tags: python, string

I have a variable that reads in a datafile

```
dfPort = pd.read_csv("E:...\Portfolios\ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv")
```

I was hoping to create three variables: portName, inceptionDate, and frequency that would read the string of the "E:..." above and take out the wanted parts of the string using the underscore as a indicator to go to next variable. Example after parsing string:

```
portName = "ConsDisc"
inceptionDate: "2016-07-01"
frequency: "Q"
```

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: `list = "E:...\Portfolios\ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv".split("\\")[-1].split(".")[0].split("_"); portName, inceptionDate, frequency = list[0], list[1], list[2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `os.path.basename`, `os.path.splitext` and `str.split`:

```
import os

filename = r'E:...\Portfolios\ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv'
parts = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(filename.replace('\\', os.sep)))[0].split('_')
print(parts)
```

outputs `['ConsDisc', '20160701', 'Q']`. You can then manipulate this list as you like, for example extract it into variables with `port_name, inception_date, frequency = parts`, etc.

The `.replace('\\', os.sep)` there is used to "normalize" Windows-style backslash-separated paths into whatever is the convention of the system the code is being run on (i.e. forward slashes on anything but Windows :) )

Comment: as the next step, is there a way of implementing this if I had the filename go only until  "E...\Portfolios" where I have several of these different 'ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv' (different variables) and it would iterate through however many files there are. (I have a program that runs one file and does something with it, then moves onto the next) Thank you so much for your help though!

Comment: Yes, that'd be the glob function from the similarly named module. `import glob; for file in glob.glob('e:\portfolios\*.csv'):... `

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

def parse_filename(path):
    filename = os.path.basename(path)
    filename_no_ext =  os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    return filename_no_ext.split("_")

path = r"Portfolios\ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv"
portName, inceptionDate, frequency = parse_filename(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about an alternative solution just in case if you want to store them into a dictionary and use them like so,

```
import re

str1 = "E:...\Portfolios\ConsDisc_20160701_Q.csv"

re.search(r'Portfolios\\(?P<portName>.*)_(?P<inceptionDate>.*)_(?P<frequency>.)', str1).groupdict()

# result
# {'portName': 'ConsDisc', 'inceptionDate': '20160701', 'frequency': 'Q'}
```